Error migrating from Anchor 0.29.0 to 0.30.1 - Unable to pass &AccountInfo as an argument to a validation function in an Instruction
I’m migrating my code from Anchor 0.29.0, where everything was working correctly.
I need to pass an account as &UncheckedAccount or &AccountInfo to a static method which extracts a value from raw data that will be used as part of the PDA seed.
Here is the code that is now broken:
#[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [ 
        UserMessageNonce::SEED_PREFIX,
        sender.key().as_ref()
    ],
    bump
)]
pub user_message_nonce: AccountInfo<'info>,

#[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [
        SEED_PREFIX_SENT,                         
        &UserMessageNonce::value(&user_message_nonce).to_le_bytes(),
        sender.key().as_ref()
    ],
    bump,
)]
pub other_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,    

When I compile this, I encounter the following error:
error[E0425]: cannot find value `user_message_nonce` in this scope
   --> programs/my_program/src/instructions/generic_send_message.rs:134:39
    |
134 |             &UserMessageNonce::value(&user_message_nonce).to_le_bytes(),
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

At the moment, the only workaround I’ve found is to avoid providing the seed in the Instruction and instead validate the account address in the code. However, this solution is neither optimal nor clear.
I’m posting this here in case there’s a simple solution that I’ve overlooked. If no solution exists, I’ll raise a GitHub issue for this.
